# Bouncy Castle Getting FipsSecureRandom

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm trying to use Bouncy Castle in approved mode (`CryptoServicesRegistrar.SetApprovedOnlyMode(true);`) and am having some trouble generating RSA keys. I keep throwing exceptions on the following line.

```
var generator = CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateGenerator(new FipsRsa.KeyGenerationParameters(BigInteger.ValueOf(65537L), 3072), FipsSecureRandom.GetInstance(FipsDrbg.CtrAes256.Algorithm.Name));
```

I have debugged the constructor, looked at the source code, and so on, but I can't figure out how to get an FSR object. All the builder methods for the object are internal to the BC library so I can't get to them. The methods provided in the FipsDrbg class are all internal as well and the provided stubs (such as `CtrAes256` in my example) don't expose it either. I've tried passing a string of a PRNG method directly to the constructor from the values I've found in the documentation such as "SHA256PRNG." This gives the following exception:

```
attempt to create key pair with unapproved RNG: RSA
```

Looking in the source, the method throwing this exception comes from a `ValidateRandom` method that checks to make sure the random instance is a `FipsSecureRandom` so it doesn't get me anywhere.

Lastly, trying to backtrack the `Builder : IDrbgBuilder<FipsSecureRandom>` class doesn't lead anywhere. They're wholly used in the `Base : Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.Parameters<FipsAlgorithm>, IDrbgBuilderService<FipsSecureRandom>` class which is completely internal. While the Builder's `Build` method is public, it's not static and the constructor is internal so I can't create an instance of it to build anything.

What am I missing?

Update:

I was asked to split out the failing line so here is that line split.

```
var rsaParams = new FipsRsa.KeyGenerationParameters(BigInteger.ValueOf(65537L), 3072);
var fipsRandom = FipsSecureRandom.GetInstance("SHA256PRNG");
var generator = CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateGenerator(rsaParams, fipsRandom);
```

The line throwing the exception is the `var generator =` line. The full exception details are such.

```
Source: "bc-fips-1.0.1"
Message: attempt to create key pair with unapproved RNG: RSA
at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Fips.Utils.ValidateRandom(SecureRandom random, Int32 securityStrength, FipsAlgorithm algorithm, String message)
at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Fips.FipsRsa.KeyPairGenerator..ctor(KeyGenerationParameters keyGenParameters, SecureRandom random)
at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Fips.FipsRsa.KeyGenerationParameters.<>c.<Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.IGenerationService<Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Fips.FipsRsa.KeyPairGenerator>.GetFunc>b__17_0(IParameters`1 parameters, SecureRandom random)
at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecurityContext.CreateGenerator[A](IGenerationServiceType`1 type, SecureRandom random)
at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateGenerator[A](IGenerationServiceType`1 type, SecureRandom random)
```

No inner exception, no exception data.

Comment: Please split the line that throws exceptions into multiple statements (using local variables to hold the results), then post the exceptions and indicate the line they occur on.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes modified

Comment: In the Java examples there is something like `new FipsDRBG.Builder(new BasicEntropySourceProvider(new SecureRandom(), true)).build(FipsDRBG.SHA512_HMAC,null,false)`. Maybe a good idea to look at constructions such as these or at least a constant such as `FipsDRBG.SHA512_HMAC`? A HMAC based RNG definitely seems a good idea and so does making the entropy source explicit (this is just taking a buckshot at the problem though, no idea if such a thing works).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It unfortunately doesn't work in C# given the access modifiers on the members. For `FipsDRBG`, it is private. For `BuilderService`, the class is public but the constructor is internal making it moot. The constructor is marked internal meaning my code can't create new instances of it. And the build method isn't static so I can't get to it without an instance. I'm wondering if this was an oversight on part of the maintainers and if I need to modify source which introduces a maintenance headache on upgrades.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, don't forget the dev mailing list of Bouncy Castle! Personally I'd just walk through the method to see which check fails and what it *does* expect.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'll take a look at that. I did walk the method. It expects the `SecureRandom` to be a `FipsSecureRandom` which is what I'm asking how to acquire.